# How to deploy this function to Google cloud?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, deployment

This api could be deployed to google cloud function?

https://github.com/Mdsp9070/someoneFlix/tree/master/backend

I tried to deploy but I'm getting this error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: main.go:16:2: import "flix-api.localhost/flix-api" is a program, not an importable package; Error ID: 975560ac`

Comment: Hello, I would recommend to follow this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http#functions-prepare-environment-go) in order to deploy a Cloud Function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the correct signature to handle functions requests

```
func myFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
...
}
```

Here you start you own web server with several endpoint. It's not a Cloud Functions pattern, but more a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) service. Try this (with the correct ProjectID)

```
gcloud alpha builds submit --pack=image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/backend && \
gcloud run deploy --platform=managed --region=us-central1 --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/backend --port=3333 --allow-unauthenticated backend
```

And call the url provided. I tested with your code and it worked on my side, I just got an error in the logs `Error on loadinf .env file`. You might have `--set-env-vars` to set to add environment variables.

If interested, I can explain more the commands

**EDIT**

Some explanations

1. Cloud Functions and Cloud Build share the same backend. Cloud Run host a webserver (in a customizable container). CLoud Function package the function into a webserver (that's why you have to respect a function signature to make it callable by the generic webserver).
2. Cloud Run can handle concurrent requests in the same instance (up to 80), Cloud Functions only 1. You can have the exact same behavior if you set the Cloud Run concurrency param to 1
3. Cloud Run need a container. When you have your code, you can write a [Dockerfile (you can find examples in the documentation)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing). You can build the container with [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs) or with [Docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/). In my code example, I used an alpha (and not documented command) of Cloud Build based on [Buildpack project](https://buildpacks.io/). Build pack detect your language, the main file and create automatically a standard container based on your code. Perfect for a quick test and containers that don't required customization.

Comment: Actually this is my question! So, I can't use gin frameword on Cloud Run instead? I would appreciate if you could give more details about these commands!

Comment: You can use Gin with Cloud Run ( I deployed a microservice in production last January with Gin inside, it works great!). But you can't use Gin with Cloud Functions (Honestly, I think that you can build a hack to use it, but it's not the purpose of Cloud Functions and it will be hard to maintain).